# special character in PHP SOAP client

Tags: php, soap

I have text values in an XML document created by the PHP SOAP client that includes an ' (that's an apostrophe). I've confirmed that the encoding is ASCII which should be valid UTF-8. I did it like this:

```
foreach ($myarrayofstrings as $s){
    echo mb_detect_encoding($s);
}
```

If I remove the apostrophe like this then the server accepts my request.

```
$myarrayofstrings = str_replace("'", "", $myarrayofstrings);
```

Question:

Is there anything I can do to ensure this works every time without the str_replace?

Comment: I think you can use [**`addslashes()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) to escape your apostrophes

Comment: Thanks Fabio, but the SOAP server rejected the string after using addslashes()

Comment: Does it accept htmlentities?

Comment: It does, but are there any trade offs in doing this?

Comment: Depends how server will handle html entities

Comment: that is totally unknown to me. I'll have to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

For me always work **utf8_encode** function instead any replace:

```
$myarrayofstrings = utf8_encode($myarrayofstrings);
```

But i think you can use `htmlspecialchars` too

```
<?php
$new = htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);
echo $new; // &lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;     
?>
```